# Problema com áudio em aplicação web com deploy em tomcat7

Tags: javascript, java, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, tomcat

Olá,

desenvolvi uma aplicação web que necessita de áudios.
Eu uso um código em javascript para controlar essa chamada de áudio.
Com a aplicação pronta, transferi para outro computador fazendo deploy no tomcat7. Tudo funciona perfeitamente, exceto a execução do áudio e o firefox retorna essas mensagens:

> O atributo HTTP "Content-Type" de "audio/mpeg" não é suportado. O carregamento do recurso multimédia http://localhost:8080/--caminho--/audio.mp3 falhou
>
> Não é possível executar mídia. Não há decodificadores para os formatos solicitados: audio/mpeg

Já verifiquei que meu ubuntu tem os codecs necessários. Qualquer áudio fora da aplicação roda perfeitamente e a aplicação sem deploy também executa o áudio.

Informações adicionais:
Uso de HTML, CSS e Javascript para a página.
Uso de servlets em Java para conexão com o banco de dados MySQL. A conexão funciona perfeitamente.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: dá para definir ficheiros de fallback noutros formatos

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou configurar no web.xml  da aplicação?

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>mp3</extension>
    <mime-type>audio/mpeg</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Isso não funcionou. Essa configuração já tinha no web.xml do tomcat e mesmo colocando no web.xml do servlet não funcionou. Mas obrigado pela resposta.